# Magento 2: How to move the tier price table under the quantity input box on product view page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, custom-template

I am working on the product catalog page using my customized theme. Is it possible to insert my customized tier_prices.phtml inside my customized addtocart.phtml file? I need to put my tier prices table under the qty input box.

This is what I want to accomplish

[image: This is what I want to accomplish]

This is the [image: screenshot] of html codes for each block ( tier_prices and addtocart). Thanks.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: could you share you page URL to inspect

Comment: im still working on my localhost. i'll update my post to include screenshots of html codes.thanks.

Comment: try with <move element="product.price.tier" destination="product.info.form.content" after="product.info.addtocart" />

Comment: it didn't work since the Add to Cart button is inside the block "product.info.addtocart" and i want to put the block "product.price.tier" between the Qty input box and Subtotal. i also tried including the tier_prices.phtml within addtocart.phtml using the "<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile(...)) ?>" command but got some errors.

Answer (score 2):

Go to below location

> Magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view

Copy file with Name **addtocart.phtml** & paste it to below location in your theme

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

Put the below code into after the Qty box. You will find qty box code in the file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render',
                  "product.price.tier",
                    [
                        'data' => [
                            'price_render' => 'product.price.render.default',
                            'price_type_code' => 'tier_price',
                            'zone' => 'item_view'
                        ]
                   ]
                  )
          ->toHtml();?>
```

Now go to the below location

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Put the below code into the file with name `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="product.price.tier" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Note: Put your cache disabled or run the below command while you are
>   doing this changes
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```